# Argument 'controller' is not a function, when ngCookies added

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to  import ngCookies in the following way in my controller. Im getting the below error when I added ngCookies.

Argument 'HomeCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Controller.js:

```
angular.module('angularRestfulAuth', ['ngCookies']);
angular.module('angularRestfulAuth')
    .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location','$cookies', '$localStorage', 'Main', function($rootScope, $scope, $location,$cookies, $localStorage, Main) {
```

Here is my service,

```
angular.module('angularRestfulAuth')
    .factory('Main', ['$http','$cookies', '$localStorage', function($http,$cookies, $localStorage){
```

my index html has ,

```
<body ng-app="angularRestfulAuth">

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" data-ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    ....
    </div>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-local-storage/0.6.0/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any problem with **ngCookies**, but if you want to use [Angular Local Storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) you need to inject it in your module :

```
angular.module('angularRestfulAuth', ['LocalStorageModule']);
```

And you can use the service in your controller or in your factory like this :

```
angular.module('angularRestfulAuth')
    .controller('HomeCtrl', ['localStorageService', function(localStorageService) {
    localStorageService.get(key);
    ...
}

angular.module('angularRestfulAuth')
    .factory('Main', ['localStorageService', function(localStorageService){
    localStorageService.get(key);
    ...
}
```

But I think you shouldn't use both, **ngCookies** and **AngularLocalStorage**, because they are both designed for the same thing, using browsers cookies (and also using local storage for **AngularLocalStorage**)

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/1ca8xxJUig348tLgkePA?p=preview) is a example of using cookies with **AngularLocalStorage**

Comment: I was using with node js app and jwt. If I store my token in localStorage, I am not able to get this at server side. It is always gives undefined.

Comment: But AngularLocalStorage allows you to use cookies

Comment: Do you have any sample links. I am new to this. Will that be available at server side as well?

Comment: I'm not on my computer right now but take a look at the [official doc](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) it's well explained

Comment: @ep I added an example to show you how to use cookies with AngularLocalStorage

Comment: @ep Did you succeeded to use cookies with AngularLocalStorage ?

Comment: The error has gone, as you mentioned, when I use localstorage without `ngCookies`. But I could not get the token value at server side. And finally I have removed localstorage and used `ngCookies` only. Now the application is working with cookies.Thanks.